# Create an app exchange listing that installs from a web site rather than a managed package

Tags: appexchange

How do I go about creating an AppExchange listing that links to a website rather than a managed package?

E.g. On some listings after pressing the "Get It Now" button an "Install from provider's site" button is provided that links to their website.

[image: AppExchange Get It Now, Instal from provider's site]

Comment: I've a query on this kind of setting. Do you know how do people Update to new package we Install from Vendor's website is enabled for listing? Going by this design, it will redirect users to external website which probably gonna have input webform to accept lead information, so every existing suer anting to update will also end up repeating the process and providing new lead from the webform - correct?

Comment: @VarunC I'd suggest asking a new question for this. Feel free to link back to this question of add a comment linking to the new question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the "Offering" tab in Publishing Console, the second question is "How should people install your application?" If you answer "Install it directly from your company’s website" you get a text box to enter your installation URL.